# Map NumPy Values

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array:

```
x = np.array([[0, 5],
              [1, 6],
              [4, 3],
              [2, 4],
              [3, 2]])
```

and a "look-up" array that tells me how to map one integer (first column) to another (second column):

```
lookup = np.array([[0, 50],
                   [1, 16],
                   [2, 47],
```

So, `0 -> 50`, `1 -> 16`, and `2 -> 47`. Notice that integers `[3, 4, 5, 6]` is not in the lookup and therefore do not need to be changed. A simple way to do this is:

```
for i in range(lookup.shape[0]):
    num = lookup[i, 0]
    x[x == num] = lookup[i, 1]
```

And the expected output should be:

```
np.array([[50, 5],
          [16, 6],
          [4, 3],
          [47, 4],
          [3, 47]])
```

For a big 2D array `x` and a much larger `lookup`, is there a more efficient way to do this in a vectorized way in NumPy?

Answer (score 0):

My approach for the case where `x` does not contain negative or big integers:

```
a = np.arange(x.max()+1)

a[lookup[:,0]] = lookup[:,1]

x = a[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
x = np.array([[0, 5],
              [1, 6],
              [4, 3],
              [2, 4],
              [3, 2]])

lookup = np.array([[0, 50],
                   [1, 16],

                   [2, 47]])

# building a dictionary
lookup = {each[0]:each[1] for each in lookup}

vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: lookup.get(x, x))

vfunc(x) # gives your result
```

output

```sh
array([[50,  5],
       [16,  6],
       [ 4,  3],
       [47,  4],
       [ 3, 47]])
```

Comment: `np.vectorize` is essentially the same `for` loop as in OP's code.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not improve the speed (compared to Python iteration).

Comment: @QuangHoang - Thank you. I did not know this. But using `dict` data type should improve the performance! The overall speed will be around O(N) which is good right?